# naming a function that switches an element between "enabled" and "disabled" states

Tags: javascript, html, naming-conventions

I was wondering what's the correct name to give to a function that switches an input (or any other element) between `enabled` and `disabled` states.

```
<input disabled type="text"> <!-- disabled state -->
<input type="text"> <!-- enabled state -->

// this function name does not satisfy me at all
function toggleEnabledDisabled(el){
    // check if the element state (enabled/disabled) and apply the opposite state
}
```

For example, `toggleVisibility` could be used to change the visibility of an element from `visible` to `hidden` and viceversa, `toggleClass` is used to add/remove a certain class, etc.

I am looking for a function name starting with *toggle*, if possible.

I realize that this is an "opinion based" question, I would appreciate if you can address me to a more appropriate SO section if there is one

Comment: @FelixKling hmmm state seems to be too much generic.. I'm looking for something more specific if possible. Thank you anyway!

Comment: How about: `toggleAbled`

Answer (score 1):

The MDN documentation for instance says the following about an input field's *disabled* attribute:

> **disabled**
>
> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not
> available for interaction. (...)

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

So maybe *toggleAvailability* would be an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose toggleDisponibility

Definition of DISPONIBLE. : capable of being placed, arranged, or disposed of as one wishes : available